# Regex to capture the first 5 groups and last character

Tags: regex, regex-group, capturing-group

I'm trying to create a regex which will extract the first 5 characters and the last character in a string no matter the size of the string. For example

For `FOO:BAR:123FF:FOO:BARF:OO:BAR:1234` or `FOO:BAR:123FF:FOO:BAR:FOO:BAR:FOO:BAR:FOO:1234` it will capture six groups which is `FOO BAR 123FF FOO BAR 1234`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your string is always formatted like this, I think it's better to use `split`

```js
let a = 'FOO:BAR:123FF:FOO:BAR:FOO:BAR:FOO:BAR:FOO:1234'
let res = a.split(':')
// Remove all between the 5th and the last element
res.splice(5, res.length - 5 - 1)

console.log(res)
```

But if you really want to use regex, it's also possible:

```js
let a = 'FOO:BAR:123FF:FOO:BAR:FOO:BAR:FOO:BAR:FOO:1234'
let regex = /^(\w+):(\w+):(\w+):(\w+):(\w+):.*:(\w+)$/

console.log(regex.exec(a).slice(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can get all the separated words with the regex below:**

```
const regex = /[^:]*\w+/g
```

**After that you can obtain all the matches with the following:**

```
const text = "FOO:BAR:123FF:FOO:BAR:FOO:BAR:FOO:BAR:FOO:1234"
const matches = text.match(regex)
```

**Finally remove the duplicates:**

```
const uniqueArr = Array.from(new Set(matches))
console.log(uniqueArr) // ["FOO", "BAR", "123FF", "FOO", "BAR", "1234"]
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: What happen if between the 6th and last there is no duplicate ?